# Intersection Observer find out element is shown or hidden

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

[Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) callback function is invoked whenever observed element is shown or hidden (when threshold point is reached)..

So can I get wether element is about to disappear or it's about to show up?

Answer (score 4):

No need to play with root margins and thresholds:

```
const callback = (entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            console.log("entering element");
        } else {
            console.log("leaving element");
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Look at the 'root margin' section and play with the options there.
Threshold is also an option of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you should take a look at the `entry.intersectionRect` property, at the level of the `top` and `bottom`properties, since it accounts for the intersection rectangle with the viewport.

Indeed, when the `top` equals `0`, it means that the observed entry is appearing from the bottom of the viewport, when `bottom` is equal to the observed entry height, it means that it is disappearing by the top.